# echo PHP variable if iframe content is empty

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have this JS / PHP Code:

```
<iframe src="" id="contacts_iframe" width="100%" height="300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
function() {
    $('#contacts_iframe').load(function() {            
        if($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").html()) == "") {
            alert("empty");
            <?php echo $ContactsDisplay; ?>
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to be able to echo the `$ContactsDisplay` variable if the iframe is empty

I added the alert in to test, but the alert does not show and neither does the PHP variable.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: That's a syntax error, PHP outputs the string long before the page reaches the browser and the javascript runs, so you have a string where it doesn't belong.

Comment: where is the syntax error?

Answer (score -2):

Your nearly there try this.

```
 if($( "#frameDemo" ).contents().length == 0){
   alert('success loaded');
 } else {
   alert('fail not loaded');
 }

success
<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

fail
<iframe src="www.sdfsdfdsf.com" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>
```

Comment: thats not working either.. just nothing at all

Comment: Odd this is working for me, what browser are you using this on and version of jQuery?

Comment: check here - http://jsfiddle.net/r496ufrs/

Comment: Odd it did before I posted it ;) anyway updated answer

Comment: I just had my iframe with no src and it was alerting the second alert, i then added in http://google.com to the src and it still shows the second alert